# Is it possible to use Plastic SCM locally while using GitHub for hosting?

Tags: git, github, plasticscm

I'm curious about [Plastic SCM](https://www.plasticscm.com), as a version control system. However, I like GitHub and don't want to move away from it. Nor do I want to continuously synchronize two repositories.

So I'd like to know this: **is it possible to use the Plastic SCM client for day-to-day version control operations while using GitHub for storage and project management?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub only supports Git and SVN as ways to interact with a repository, so you can't host a Plastic SCM repository there.

Plastic SCM does support the standard fast-import and fast-export functionality, so you could export your data to a Git repository that you hosted on GitHub, provided that you were conscientious about compatibility (such as not using branches with spaces) and didn't really want to make any modifications on GitHub.  I doubt this is going to be a satisfying workflow, though.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what project management options you want to be able to access.

Plastic SCM provides a way to sync repositories with Github via their GitSync feature. I have tried it myself and worked perfectly to sync a github repository with PlasticSCM cloud repository. I used it mainly for Unity Cloud Builds since there was no support for PlasticSCM back in the time.
Read more about PlasticSCM GitSync here https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/gitsync/plastic-scm-version-control-gitsync-guide